# In ggproto, coord$transform did not transform some columns to [0, 1]

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

I want to create a new Geom type: geom_ohlc(), which is something like Candlestick Charts, to plot the stock open-high-low-close data.

After learning this [Hadley's article](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html): I tried this:

```
GeomOHLC <- ggproto(`_class` = "GeomOHLC", `_inherit` = Geom,

                 required_aes = c("x", "op", "hi", "lo", "cl"),

                 draw_panel = function(data, panel_scales, coord){

                   coords <- coord$transform(data, panel_scales)
                   browser() # <<-- here is where I found the problem
                   grid::gList(
                     grid::rectGrob(
                       x = coords$x,
                       y = pmin(coords$op, coords$cl),
                       vjust = 0,
                       width = 0.01,
                       height = abs(coords$op - coords$cl),
                       gp = grid::gpar(col = coords$color, fill = "yellow")
                     ),
                     grid::segmentsGrob(
                       x0 = coords$x,
                       y0 = coords$lo,
                       x1 = coords$x,
                       y1 = coords$hi
                       )
                   )
                 })
    geom_ohlc <- function(data = NULL, mapping = NULL, stat = "identity", position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE, ...)
    {
      layer(
        geom = GeomOHLC, mapping = mapping, data = data, 
        stat = stat, position = position, show.legend = show.legend, 
        inherit.aes = inherit.aes, params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)
      )
    }   
    dt <- data.table(x = 1:10, open = 1:10, high = 3:12, low = 0:9, close = 2:11)
    p <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = x, op = open, hi = high, lo = low, cl = close)) + 
      geom_ohlc() 
    p
```

for simplicity, i just do not consider the color of bar.

The result plot is like this:

[image: screenshot]

I add a `browser()` inside the `ggproto` function, and I found that the `coord$transform` did not transform the `op`, `hi`, `lo`, `cl` aesthetics into interverl [0,1]. How to fix this problem ?

Moreover, is there any other documents about how to create your own Geom type except that Hadley's article ?

Comment: The blame seems to be `transform_position()` called by the function in `coord$transform`. The code shows that it will only transform the columns in the data.frame named `x` and `y`. I do not know of a solution to your problem but I would try to think whether you *need them* to be rescaled (?).

Comment: Although on second thought the same code also suggests the possibility of several of the scales being "x" and/or "y". Maybe there is something there?

Comment: Furthermore, the function `ggplot2:::aes_to_scale` is the one mapping the `data.frame` names to whether they are `x` or `y` scale. Looking at the documentation you need to use `"x", "xmin", "xmax", "xend", "xintercept"` or the equivalent aesthetics for y axis. It is mentioned also in `?transform_position`. I think that If you can figure out a way to map your variables to those you will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments under the OP's question the problem is `aes_to_scale()` function inside `transform_position()`, which in turn is called by `coord$transform`. Transformations are limited to variables named `x, xmin, xmax, xend, xintercept` and the equivalents for y axis. This is mentioned in the help for transform_position:

> Description
>
> Convenience function to transform all position variables.
>
> Usage
>
> transform_position(df, trans_x = NULL, trans_y = NULL, ...) Arguments
>
> trans_x, trans_y   Transformation functions for x and y aesthetics.
>   (will transform x, xmin, xmax, xend etc) ...   Additional arguments
>   passed to trans_x and trans_y.

A workaround would be to use those variable names instead of the variable names used by the OP. The following code works in transforming the variables but it fails at somewhere else (see at the end). I do not know the details of the intended plot, so didn't try to fix this error.

```
GeomOHLC <- ggproto(
  `_class` = "GeomOHLC",
  `_inherit` = Geom,

  required_aes = c("x", "yintercept", "ymin", "ymax", "yend"),

  draw_panel = function(data, panel_scales, coord) {
    coords <- coord$transform(data, panel_scales)
    #browser() # <<-- here is where I found the problem
    grid::gList(
      grid::rectGrob(
        x = coords$x,
        y = pmin(coords$yintercept, coords$yend),
        vjust = 0,
        width = 0.01,
        height = abs(coords$op - coords$cl),
        gp = grid::gpar(col = coords$color, fill = "yellow")
      ),
      grid::segmentsGrob(
        x0 = coords$x,
        y0 = coords$ymin,
        x1 = coords$x,
        y1 = coords$ymax
      )
    )
  }
)
geom_ohlc <-
  function(data = NULL,
           mapping = NULL,
           stat = "identity",
           position = "identity",
           na.rm = FALSE,
           show.legend = NA,
           inherit.aes = TRUE,
           ...)
  {
    layer(
      geom = GeomOHLC,
      mapping = mapping,
      data = data,
      stat = stat,
      position = position,
      show.legend = show.legend,
      inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
      params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)
    )
  }
dt <-
  data.table(
    x = 1:10,
    open = 1:10,
    high = 3:12,
    low = 0:9,
    close = 2:11
  )
p <-
  ggplot(dt, aes(
    x = x,
    yintercept = open,
    ymin = high,
    ymax = low,
    yend = close
  )) +
  geom_ohlc()
p
```

This transforms the variables but produces the following error:

```
Error in unit(height, default.units) : 
  'x' and 'units' must have length > 0
```

But hopefully from here it can be made to work.

NOTE: I chose the mapping between the original variable names (op, hi, lo, cl) rather arbitrarily. Specially `yintercept` does not seem to fit well. Maybe there is need to support arbitrary scale variable names in ggplot2?

Comment: I think you got the point. I try to  change the column names of `data` inside the `draw_panel` function , from `op, hi, lo, cl` to `y, ymax, ymin, yend`. Then the `coords$transfrom` "knows" to transform these columns into [0, 1].